# Reorder View Controllers in UITabBarController in a Storyboard (XCode 4.6)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode4.6

That issue again...

I have a UITabBarController in a Storyboard and want to reorder the Tabs there.

I tried all the suggested solutions I could find in previous posts (Simple Drag & Drop, Restart XCode, Open Storyboard as Source Code, touching left ear with right big toe while clapping hands behind back), of which none of them worked for me.

Does anyone have a working solution in XCode 4.6 for that?

**EDIT:**
I created a new project to see if there is any difference and, alas, Drag & Drop is working perfectly fine there. Any ideas/thoughts if I missed some build/storyboard/project setting (I couldn't see any differences so far).

Comment: I just dragged the tabs around (where they appear in the tab bar controller) in IB without trouble...

Comment: @rickster thx for having a look, weirdly enough, I just created a new project and in the new one its working perfectly fine...but in the one where I want to change it its still not working at all. Do you happen to have any idea if it could be due to some build/project/storyboard setting?

Comment: This happened to me whenever I used a UINavigationController as one of the tabs. This resulted in the UITabBarController being just dark grey with none of the actual tabs available to drag around. In this case deleting all of the connections and re-adding as per the solution from @jhilgert00 worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always delete the "relationship" segues from the TabBarController to ViewControllers in the storyboard, then hook them back up one by one in the order you want.

Comment: i actually wanted to avoid this (as its a bit of a pain) as i'll (almost certainly) need to change the order for subsequent releases again, but if nothing else works, i guess it will be the way to go. cheers